# Objects not appearing in Camera view

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, camera

There seems to be a limit to where my camera dsitance from the objects can be... How do I fix this? because I want to get the whole of my fortress in the camera, but this happens.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @cegaton - thank you, how do i remove this question?

Comment: No need to remove it. Maybe it will help other users find the information they are looking for.